# Selected File Removed on validating and change event of Radio button with update panel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

In my ASPX form I have **Update Panel**  and **Script Manager** too.
When I am changing Radio button **oncheckedChanged** All selected file will be removed from my aspx file as well as when I submit the form if validation occurs then also file will be removed from fileupload controller.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="text-success">
            <span><strong>અરજદારનું નામ ચાલે છે કે કેમ? </strong>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdBtnYes" runat="server" Text="હા" GroupName="binKhetidetails" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdBtnYes_CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdBtnNo" runat="server" Text="ના" Checked="True" GroupName="binKhetidetails" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdBtnNo_CheckedChanged" /></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="text-success">
            <strong>File Upload</strong>
        </div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept=".pdf, image/*"></asp:FileUpload>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio button will do a postback and refresh the page, which means it will be fresh, the way it started. Try putting the buttons in an update panel but not the fileupload (which is not designed to work in an update panel anyway). Not sure if that will solve it though.

Comment: Most file up-loaders don't work nor allow a page post-back, they will lose their settings. However, if you place the radio button part in a update panel, and the file up-loader outside of that panel, then a good chance that can work. But, during the file selection process and until you start the up-load, as a general rule you can't have a post back in that process - else the up-load controls values are lost. So try the radio buttons and whatever inside of a update-panel - but the file up-load control will have to be outside of the update panel, and up-load controls don't survive round trips.

Comment: Hello, Albert D. Kallal
I tried it before but it is not working

Thank You For Your Valuable Answer.